# How do I disable structure guidelines in Visual Studio community 2015

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to disable the structure guidelines, the ones you can collapse. I don't want them; for me they are annoying. Is there a way to disable them so that just the line numbers show?

Answer (score 1):

These things, right?

[image: Plus and minus signs in the left hand gutter used to expand and collapse blocks of code.]

Disable Outlining

- Right click in source file -> Outlining -> Stop outlining [Ctrl-M + Ctrl-P]
- Make sure this is not enabled in Tools -> Options -> Text editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Enter outlining mode when files open

Enable line numbers
Tools -> Options -> Text editor -> C# -> General -> Line numbers